# How to create a conditional RegEx to check product input?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to write a simple regular expression to validate a product code as input from the user.

This product code has some rules to be respected as below:

- 1group: (S)
- 2group: (B|S|T|M)
- 3group: (20)
- 4group: (-)
- 5group: (0|1) -> option '1' is valid when group number 2 is option **T or M**, for **B and S** shall be '0'

To match those conditions, I have created this regex:

```
(S)([B|S|T|M])(20)(-)([0|1])
```

Input to be tested:

- SS20-0 => OK
- SS20-1 => NOK
- ST20-0 => OK
- ST20-1 => OK

Great, it works partially, but how can I create a special condition into group 5 to check those rules?
[image]

Comment: You say *option '1' is valid when group number 2 is option T or M* but `ST20-0` is OK? Shouldn't that be invalid, by your logic, since it's T with option 0?

Comment: Group 2 will drive group 5: 
if group 2 is **S or B** group 5 shall be **0**
if group 2 is **T or M**, group 5 shall be **0 or 1**
Any way to create a regex to check those conditionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X15_Light,

Here you go:

```
(S)((B|S)|(T|M))(20)(-)(?(3)0|(0|1))
```

([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/031Dxl/1))

The conditional group structure looks like this:

```
(?(1)Pattern1|Pattern2)
```

Where (1) is a reference to a group. If group 1 returns a match then match Pattern1 else match Pattern2.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your OR-ing doesn't work like you think it does.  When you put stuff inside square brackets `[]`, it turns it into a character class, which means the pipe character `|` just means a literal pipe, not an OR.  To fix this, take away the square brackets.  Now, answering your question:

Since you only have two possible conditions, you could just write them out as two separate branches, like so:

```
(S)(B|S)(20)(-)(0)|(S)(T|M)(20)(-)(1)
```

Alternatively, you could just put `B|S` and `T|M` in separate capturing groups, and then you could test which one found a match.  This is more in line with how you described the problem, but it seems more complex than necessary.  Note the conditional syntax at the end of the pattern `(?(2)0|1)`.  This means only match the pattern `0` if capturing group 2 matched something.  Else match the pattern `1`.  We know that if capturing group 2 matched nothing, capturing group 3 *must* have matched something because otherwise the match would have failed.

```
(S)(?:(B|S)|(T|M))(20)(-)((?(2)0|1))
```

Answer (score 0):

When matching group 2, if B or S is matched, lookahead for `20-0` to make sure that the final group is 0:

https://regex101.com/r/VEhnHC/1

```
(S)([BS](?=20-0)|[TM])(20)(-)([01])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the regex below, and it works perfectly.

```
(S)(?:(B|S)|(T|M))(20)(-)((?(2)0|[0|1]))
```

Comment: Try running `ST20-|` through and see what happens.  I don't think you understand what `[0|1]` does.  This says "match a `0`, a `|`, or a `1`".  I believe you want it to say "match a `0` or a `1`".  In this case you want either `[01]` or `(?:0|1)`.